# How to replace line break in a textarea preview?

Tags: javascript, replace, getelementbyid

I want to preserve line break (input by Enter key) in the preview of [mathjax dynamic](http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic-2.html), I try to do it by javascript (since I think they don't load jquery) `replace` function, but failed with the hint that `getElementById` returns a `div` tag, not a string.

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Set CSS style `white-space: pre;` in the preview `div`

Comment: @RolandJansen That's really help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I did the following test on a javascript console:

```
var text = document.getElementById('MathInput').value;
text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
document.getElementById('MathPreview').innerHTML = text;`
```

Comment: I don't understand, could u give more detail? e.g., how to modefiy the mathbuffer variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
text.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "<br />");
```